# how to encrypt and decrypt my application database in android

Tags: android, encryption, sqlite

My problem is that how to secure my application database file using encryption algorithm if i use hardcoded key then after decompiling it will be also accessible.if device is rooted then anyone can access my db file so i want to secure my db that is not accessible or readable by anyone. thanks in advance

Comment: I think there are companies who are trying to solve the issue of Mobile App Integrity solutions. For eg: http://www.arxan.com/

Comment: Please see this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    package com.kushal.utils;

    import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
    import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
    import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
    import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

    public class DESedeEncryption {

        private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";
        public static final String DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DESede";
        private KeySpec myKeySpec;
        private SecretKeyFactory mySecretKeyFactory;
        private Cipher cipher;
        byte[] keyAsBytes;
        private String myEncryptionKey;
        private String myEncryptionScheme;
        SecretKey key;

        public DESedeEncryption() throws Exception
        {
            myEncryptionKey = "ThisIsSecretEncryptionKey";
            myEncryptionScheme = DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME;
            keyAsBytes = myEncryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
            myKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyAsBytes);
            mySecretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
            key = mySecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(myKeySpec);
        }

        /**
         * Method To Encrypt The String
         */
        public String encrypt(String unencryptedString) {
            String encryptedString = null;
            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
                byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
                byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
                BASE64Encoder base64encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
                encryptedString = base64encoder.encode(encryptedText);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return encryptedString;
        }
        /**
         * Method To Decrypt An Ecrypted String
         */
        public String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
            String decryptedText=null;
            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
                BASE64Decoder base64decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
                byte[] encryptedText = base64decoder.decodeBuffer(encryptedString);
                byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
                decryptedText= bytes2String(plainText);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return decryptedText;
        }
        /**
         * Returns String From An Array Of Bytes
         */
        private static String bytes2String(byte[] bytes) {
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i &amp;lt; bytes.length; i++) {
                stringBuffer.append((char) bytes[i]);
            }
            return stringBuffer.toString();
        }

        /**
         * Testing The DESede Encryption And Decryption Technique
         */
        public static void main(String args []) throws Exception
        {
            DESedeEncryption myEncryptor= new DESedeEncryption();

            String stringToEncrypt=&quot;Sanjaal.com&quot;;
            String encrypted=myEncryptor.encrypt(stringToEncrypt);
            String decrypted=myEncryptor.decrypt(encrypted);

            System.out.println("String To Encrypt: "+stringToEncrypt);
            System.out.println("Encrypted Value :" + encrypted);
            System.out.println("Decrypted Value :"+decrypted);

        }

    }

output:
String To Encrypt: Sanjaal.com
Encrypted Value :aArhqI25Y1SkYrdv9gxYDQ==
Decrypted Value :Sanjaal.com

http://sanjaal.com/java/189/java-encryption/tutorial-encryption-and-decryption-using-desede-triple-des-in-java/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sqlite cipher` to encrypt your database. and store your key in parts.and generate your key at runtime. you can not prevent anyone from de-compiling your application. all you can do is to make it too difficult for the de-compiler to understand your algo. you can try obfuscation on your application.

use [dexGuard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard) to encrypt Strings of your application.